# fill canvas with linear gradient

Tags: javascript, canvas

trying to write some code which will do the following things.

user will choose a color by clicking on it and a canvas element will be filled with that color used as gradient along with a fixed white color.code seems not working .

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#chart{width:80px;height:80px;position:fixed;top:20px;left:20px;}
#mycanvas{width:200px;height:150px;position:fixed;top:250px;left:200px;border:1px solid black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function mygradient(colors){
     var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');
     var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
     var grad=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,190,0);
     grad.addColorStop(0,colors);
grad.addColorStop(1,"white");
     ctx.fillStyle=grad;
     ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,0);
}
</script>
<table id="chart">
<tr>
<td bgColor="#FF8000" onClick="mygradient(this.bgColor);"></td>
<td bgColor="#FFBF00" onClick="mygradient(this.bgColor);"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<canvas id="mycanvas"style=""></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked on it a bit and now it works:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#chart{width:80px;height:80px;position:fixed;top:20px;left:20px;}
#mycanvas{width:200px;height:150px;position:fixed;top:250px;left:200px;border:1p    x solid black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function mygradient(colors){
 var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');
 var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
 var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);
 grd.addColorStop(0,colors);
 grd.addColorStop(1,"white");

ctx.fillStyle=grd;
ctx.fillRect(20,20,150,100);
}
</script>
<table id="chart">
<tr>
<td bgColor="#FF8000" onClick="mygradient(this.bgColor);"></td>
<td bgColor="#FFBF00" onClick="mygradient(this.bgColor);"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<canvas id="mycanvas"style=""></canvas>
</body>
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/4MBtp/

Comment: it would be great if you mention the  mistakes i made  in my code??

Comment: a height of 0 does not show anything:   ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,0);   it should be ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,150);

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **Thou art amazing** beat me to it, and I used jQuery--so I probably get points off for including a library you didn't ask for.

But on a serious note, don't use bgColor, its deprecated!

Here's what I had--

JS:

```
var $swatch = $(".swatch");
$swatch.click(function (e) {

    color = $(this).css("background-color");
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    grd.addColorStop(0, color);
    grd.addColorStop(1, '#fff');
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.fill();

});
```

HTML:

```
  <table id="chart">
    <tr>
      <td class="swatch orange"></td>
      <td class="swatch yellow"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
#chart {
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: #FFBF00;
}
.orange {
    background-color: #FF8000;
}
#myCanvas {
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    position:fixed;
    top:250px;
    left:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kmblackwood/z8UTa/2/